# Socket-io client keeps sending connect requests

Tags: node.js, windows, websocket, socket.io, webpack-dev-server

I am creating app that includes some real-time features. I use `Node.js`, `SocketIO` and `Express` + `React` on frontend. My backend handles both `http` and `ws` requests. I use `webpack-dev-server` with proxy option to redirect client's requests to my local server.

Some days ago, although I haven't touch neither webpack configuration nor backend code, single call `io({ path: '/socket' })` on client side results in sending A LOT of connect requests to my backend.

The reason is not HMR, component's rerendering or some loop on client side. I am sure client side calls `io({ path: '/socket' })` only once. Even when I change branches to some old ones (in which the problem for sure didn't exist), after reinstalling all `node_modules`, the issue remains. So this can be some network/hardware related even. I use Windows 10, Node.js 6.

Exemplary logs in debug mode that my backend produces in the console:

[image]

This is only part of logs, in general it keeps connecting really fast and doesn't stop.

Any idea what is going on here?

Comment: One common reason why it won't get out of polling is if you have mismatched client and server versions of socket.io.  That causes a server disconnect before socket.io completes the transition to webSocket.  Since you don't show any of your code, we have no idea where you are getting the client-side socket.io code from or whether it's the exact same version as what you're running on the server.

Comment: Thanks but I have the same versions

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The problem was that `socket.io` kept using long polling even if websocket was already available. To solve this I passed `transports: ['websocket']` to connection options like this:

```
import io from 'socket.io-client';
io({ path: '/socket', transports: ['websocket'] });
```